# parsing json from google distance matrix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

In a rails application, the query to google's distance matrix returns proper data.  The controller generates the result in an object

```
matrix.origins << origin
matrix.destinations << destination
matrix.data
@data = matrix.data
```

which is an array of hashes. the instance variable `@data`

returns `[[#<GoogleDistanceMatrix::Route origin: #<GoogleDistanceMatrix::Place lat: 61.1173, lng: 13.8875>, destination: #<GoogleDistanceMatrix::Place lat: 61.3405325, lng: 13.7243266>, status: "ok", distance_text: "56.9 km", distance_in_meters: 56948, duration_text: "1 hour 6 mins", duration_in_seconds: 3944>]]`

However the `<%= data["distance_text"].to_s %>` statement generates a `no implicit conversion of String into Integer` when I am not interested in the integer.  Thus I suspect it is calling the index, when I expected the `each` command to handle it.  How can this be done properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is using the index, use it!

```
<% @data.each do |index, data| %>
  <div class="small-2 medium-2 large-2 columns text-center">
    <%= index.distance_text %> 
  </div>
  <div class="small-2 medium-2 large-2 columns text-center">
    <%= index.duration_text %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ruby 2.3x or greater

```
@data.dig(0,0,:distance_text)
```

OR

```
@data[0][0]["distance_text"]
```

Comment: First returns `undefined method `dig' for #<Array:`   Latter returns `undefined method `[]' for #<GoogleDistanceMatrix:`